# DateTime offset issue with AJAX

Tags: javascript, asp.net, datetime, rad-controls, timezone-offset

This is more of a KB than a question. Recently I faced an interesting issue and provided a work around solution. Thought to share.

**Environment:** .NET 3.5, ASP.NET Web forms Application using javascript, RadControls

**Problem:** Our Client in NZ when saving date with RadDatePicker was decrementing the date by 1 while saving.

**Investigation:** I found that this only was happening for timezone set as NZ with daylight saving on the client machine (browser machine), because of some clever code, else it would happen in all + time zones.

**Cause:** The RadControl GetDate() method was returning datetime with time offset viz. 15/10/2013 00:00:00 UTC +13. So when the javascript was passing the datetime to handler method via AJAX the .NET method was subtracting the UTC offset (+13 in this case). Hence the date was getting decremented by 1. It was hidden from us till now as a clever code was adding 12 hours to the time. So when the server was adding or subtracting upto 12 hours from UTC the date remained the same. But now for NZ with daylight saving it was +13 hours.

**Workaround:** For the time being we increased from adding 12 to 13 hours (not so clever). We cannot use ToLocalTime() method of .NET as it would give server time. Other possible solution may be to send only the date to the .NET method from javascript. Also looking at using DateTimeOffset class instead of DateTime class of .NET.

Comment: It's unclear what your workaround is actually doing, or if you are still having an issue.  You should post some code to go along with your description.  But in general, you want to avoid any use of "local" date functions in a web app, because that means local to the server - not the user.

Comment: You can avoid all these issues by always passing UTC time values around and only ever convert to local time for display. Then you never need to worry about timezones or offsets.